# Wordpress post displays html table incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, html, html-table

I recently tried implementing the post with emails feature on Wordpress. We use the mailchimp services that generates these great looking emails.

But when Wordpress posts these email posts it looks very weird on the site.

[live post displaying weird grid on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3EiV.png)

In the Wordpress visual editor however, it looks perfect. Anyone know the cause of this???

[visual editor displaying table just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgL2x.png)

I had to cut the code snippet short because of the character limit:

```html
<div dir="ltr">
<div class="gmail_quote">
<div style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; background-color: #dddddd;">
<table id="m_3750748612643477356bodyTable" style="border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; background-color: #dddddd;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="m_3750748612643477356bodyCell" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; border-top: 0;" align="center" valign="top">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<table id="m_3750748612643477356templatePreheader" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #ff7f50; border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356templateContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356preheaderContainer" style="padding-top: 9px; padding-bottom: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width: 390px; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContent" style="word-break: break-word; color: #f5f5f5; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px; line-height: 125%; text-align: left; padding: 0 18px 9px 18px;" valign="top">Voulez-vous lire ceci en français? Envoyer un courriel à <u></u><u><a href="mailto:communications@uottawaess.ca">communications@uottawaess.ca</a></u> pour changer votre langue de préférence.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width: 210px; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContent" style="word-break: break-word; color: #f5f5f5; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px; line-height: 125%; text-align: left; padding: 0 18px 9px 18px;" valign="top"><a style="color: #f5f5f5; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;" href="http://mailchi.mp/28c0a1246cb6/and-so-it-begins?e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener">View this email in your browser</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<table id="m_3750748612643477356templateHeader" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #f5f5f5; border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356templateContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356headerContainer" style="padding-top: 9px; padding-bottom: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageBlockInner" style="padding: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageContent" style="text-align: center; padding: 0 9px 0 9px;" valign="top"><img class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImage" style="max-width: 417px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline!important; vertical-align: bottom; border: 0; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none;" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730/images/5e22a13b-a7d1-48cb-9f97-ca3f6be6bfc4.png" alt="" width="417" align="middle" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<table id="m_3750748612643477356templateColumns" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #f5f5f5; border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-top: 9px; padding-bottom: 9px;" align="center" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356templateContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356columnsContainer" align="left" valign="top" width="33%">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356templateColumn" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356leftColumnContainer" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContent" style="word-break: break-word; color: #404040; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left; padding: 0 18px 9px 18px;" valign="top">
<h4 style="display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; line-height: 125%; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: left; color: #101010!important;">About Us</h4>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContent" style="word-break: break-word; color: #404040; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left; padding: 0 18px 9px 18px;" valign="top">The ESS represents uOttawa Engineering students; this is your association. Get involved in your student community. You’ll come to know your colleagues better by participating in the various activities and events put on by and for students.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356columnsContainer" align="left" valign="top" width="33%">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356templateColumn" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356centerColumnContainer" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContent" style="word-break: break-word; color: #404040; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left; padding: 0 18px 9px 18px;" valign="top">
<h4 style="display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; line-height: 125%; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: left; color: #101010!important;">The Office</h4>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContent" style="word-break: break-word; color: #404040; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left; padding: 0 18px 9px 18px;" valign="top">Come visit our office at CBY A05 for event tickets, engineering merch or just to chat!</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnButtonBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnButtonBlockInner" style="padding: 0 18px 18px 18px;" align="center" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnButtonContentContainer" style="border-collapse: separate!important; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #ff7f50;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnButtonContent" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; padding: 15px;" align="center" valign="middle"><a class="m_3750748612643477356mcnButton" style="font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 100%; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; display: block;" title="Office Hours" href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage1.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=b8ff6be502&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Office Hours</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356columnsContainer" align="left" valign="top" width="33%">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356templateColumn" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356rightColumnContainer" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContent" style="word-break: break-word; color: #404040; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left; padding: 0 18px 9px 18px;" valign="top">
<h4 style="display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; line-height: 125%; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: left; color: #101010!important;">Keep Up With Us</h4>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowBlockInner" style="padding: 9px;" align="center" valign="top">
<table style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left: 9px; padding-right: 9px;" align="left">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowContentContainer" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowContent" style="padding: 10px;" align="left" valign="top">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowContentItem" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;" align="left" valign="top" width="24"><a href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=7b60eea995&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="display: block; border: 0; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none;" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-facebook-48.png" width="24" height="24" /></a></td>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowTextContent" style="padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;" valign="middle"><a style="color: #ff7f50; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; line-height: 100%; text-align: center;" href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=1ed0fbdfb2&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Like our Page</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowContentItem" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;" align="left" valign="top" width="24"><a href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=b524224735&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="display: block; border: 0; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none;" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-twitter-48.png" width="24" height="24" /></a></td>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowTextContent" style="padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;" valign="middle"><a style="color: #ff7f50; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; line-height: 100%; text-align: center;" href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=4aaecd2094&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Follow us on Twitter</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowContentItem" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;" align="left" valign="top" width="24"><a href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage2.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=dd8ff5a921&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="display: block; border: 0; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none;" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-link-48.png" width="24" height="24" /></a></td>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowTextContent" style="padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;" valign="middle"><a style="color: #ff7f50; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; line-height: 100%; text-align: center;" href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage1.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=b91086daff&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Visit our Website</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowContentItem" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;" align="left" valign="top" width="24"><a href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage1.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=a6fd258ef6&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="display: block; border: 0; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none;" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-snapchat-48.png" width="24" height="24" /></a></td>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowTextContent" style="padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 10px;" valign="middle"><a style="color: #ff7f50; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; line-height: 100%; text-align: center;" href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage1.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=e689fd24a7&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Add us on Snapchat</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowContentItem" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" align="left" valign="top" width="24"><a href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage1.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=919f6b65fd&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img style="display: block; border: 0; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none;" src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-instagram-48.png" width="24" height="24" /></a></td>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnFollowTextContent" style="padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" valign="middle"><a style="color: #ff7f50; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; line-height: 100%; text-align: center;" href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=42de57f659&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Follow us on Instagram</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<table id="m_3750748612643477356templateBody" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #f5f5f5; border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356templateContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 9px 5px 18px 5px;" align="center" valign="top">
<table id="m_3750748612643477356bodyBackground" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356bodyContainer" style="padding-top: 9px; padding-bottom: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContent" style="word-break: break-word; color: #202020; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left; padding: 0 18px 9px 18px;" valign="top">
<div style="text-align: center;"><u><a style="color: #ff7f50; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;" href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage1.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=590684e763&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span style="font-size: 18px;">MEME OF THE WEEK - SUBMIT YOUR MEME HERE</span></a></u></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageBlockInner" style="padding: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImageContent" style="text-align: center; padding: 0 9px 0 9px;" valign="top"><img class="m_3750748612643477356mcnImage" style="max-width: 800px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline!important; vertical-align: bottom; border: 0; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none;" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730/images/96fe16e8-16e2-4944-81c2-54aca62ac7f7.jpg" alt="" width="553" align="middle" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnDividerBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed!important;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnDividerBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width: 100%; padding: 20px 18px;">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnDividerContent" style="min-width: 100%; border-top: 1px dotted #dddddd; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlock" style="min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top: 9px;" valign="top">
<table class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContentContainer" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="m_3750748612643477356mcnTextContent" style="word-break: break-word; color: #202020; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; line-height: 150%; text-align: left; padding: 0 18px 9px 18px;" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 22px;">CBY Locker Rentals</span>

Today begins our semester office hours: <u><a style="color: #ff7f50; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;" href="http://essaeg.us1.list-manage2.com/track/click?u=6c568a3edbc4d02372a957730&amp;id=7e79cc5e54&amp;e=0c89f1bb76" target="_blank" rel="noopener">https://essaeg.ca/contact-us/</a></u>
Come by and benefit from our many services or buy a locker and some swag!
```

Answer (score 0):

The frontend of your site is likely applying certain CSS styles to these tables that the backend isn't, hence the difference. Best bet is to inspect the affected elements using your browser's dev tools (right-click + 'Inspect element', usually).

Also, these kind of nested tables are *not* the best way to do layouts on the web (that's what CSS is for)! The *exception* is HTML emails (because email clients don't generally support CSS that well).

Comment: Yes I've heard it is bad practice to use nested tables. As this is the only code i have, I'd like to make it work. 
I'm looking at the inspect elements and I'm not really sure how to fix the problem. 
In any case, thanks for the helpful reply.